# Setting iPython default profile

Tags: ipython

Right after installing IPython, I created a **default profile** with:

```
$ ipython profile create
```

Then, I created another one, this time I gave it the name **testing**:

```
$ ipython profile create testing
```

I have customized this **testing** profile (the prompt, and autoreload extension, etc) to my liking, and now I would like it to be my default profile, so it's started when I type:

```
$ ipython
```

I know that I can start it with:

```
$ ipython --profile=testing
```

But that is a lot of typing.

I have already tried editing the file `ipython_config.py` in the `profile_default` folder, **line 89**:

```
# The IPython profile to use.
c.TerminalIPythonApp.profile = 'testing'
```

But it's not working. Any ideas why? Is it broken?

EDIT: Since I have to use different profiles for periods of time of weeks or fortnights, I'm looking for a way of selecting a **default profile** for those periods of time. It would be awesome achieving that from **IPython** itself, in the meantime, a very convenient workaround is adding an alias in the bash configuration(as pointed out by **cel** in one of the comments):

```
alias ipython='ipython --profile=testing'
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a backup of `profile_default` and then rename `profile_testing` to `profile_default`.

Or you can copy the contents of `profile_testing` to `profile_default`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple workaround, but what I'm trying to find out is how to tell ipython the **default** profile I want to start with every time I start session.
Imagine I have to copy and rename folders every time I want to set a default profile, what in my case happens every couple of weeks.
You realize that is simpler just starting IPython with ``$ ipython --profile=testing``, right?

Comment: I do not have to create profiles so often. I just use history to run the long command with the required profile specified, which is usually hitting less keystrokes and then typing `ipython`.

Comment: you can also set a shell alias for `ipython --profile=testing`

Comment: @cel Right on, another workaround but very convenient, as a matter of fact I was using it right now. Thanks cel.