# How to reset iPython/Jupyter profile after upgrade to 'factory' defaults?

Tags: linux, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Returning to using iPython Notebooks after a year, [I installed my distro's version of Jupyter and now] Jupyter launches without menu bar. I'm guessing some of my old settings are carrying over. I'm guessing the fastest way to fix this is to .bak the old profile and create a new default.

First, initialized a Jupyter profile from [instructions on how-to setup multiple Jupyter profiles](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/7q02jjksvFU):

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then, [after further investigation] I created a new iPython profile,

```
$ ipython profile create foo
```

I followed [found advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253864/setting-ipython-default-profile) to renamed `profile_foo` to `profile_default`. Then,

Still not reset to 'factory'. What am I missing?

UPDATE: [edit] plus, I reordered what were my actual rebuilding profiles steps--in case there is some propagation of settings, where the order matters (haha. Maybe I'm recreating the incorrect order...?)

Comment: Try deleting (or renaming, for safety) the whole `~/.jupyter/` directory.

Comment: Don't forget to do a hard-refresh afterwards. See Thomas' post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944204/jupyter-custom-css-removal).

Comment: Fixed! I only just started using Jupyter (and not iPython notebook). I wonder if this was the problem (unless I need to do these things in a specific order?) I had read that same link about cache clearing, but I think I did the step out of order. And, maybe I was conservative in clearing the cache in Chrome, clearing only  "Cookies and other site data". I also cleared "Cached images and files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

I'm guessing there is a directed-ness to the Jupyter system (python, ipython, jupyter, a browser) where I have to reset parts in order.

I will take a guess and put these in a specific order. (Others can reorder if this turns out meaningful):

1. Update python packages
2. Created a new iPython profile: `$ ipython profile create foo`
3. Rename `profile_foo` to `profile_default`
4. Initialize a Jupyter profile: `$ jupyter notebook --generate-config`
5. Clear the cache in your browser **:

   - Chrome (v52),

     - "Cookies and other site data"
     - "Cached images and files"
   - Firefox (v47),

     - "Offline web content and user data"
     - "Cached web content"

**CAUTION**: I'm assuming any existing iPython/Jupyter settings are not an issue, because the goal is to *restore to factory*, so to speak. And, I'm also assuming you're trying not to delete your saved passwords or bookmarks or history during a browser cache clearing step.

** I'm not clear which cache settings specifically *include* iPython/Jupyter data. These are only the settings I used and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Could you please share the command you used to rename `profile_foo`?

Comment: I just deleted the existing default profile and rename the foo to default. Here are the commands `rm -r profile_default && mv profile_foo profile_default`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `jupyter --paths` to get a list of all the places Jupyter is storing dynamic data. That includes configuration + extensions + kernel information.

For me it looked like something like this:

```
$ jupyter --paths
config:
    /home/username/.jupyter
    /home/username/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/username/Library/Jupyter
    /home/username/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /home/username/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

**At your own risk**: I just `rm -r`'ed every single directory listed by `jupyter --paths`, and that gave me a fresh "factory defaults" jupyter environment.

Comment: Thank you! I spent two hours trying to solve this and your solution finally did it for me.

Comment: thanks! kernel.json in my base kernel somehow got set to a deleted env's python