# Ubuntu WSL: sudo mv <old_folder> <new_folder> gives permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, mv

I want to rename a folder `profile_default` to `profile_default_bak` (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/39057820/12201164 )
however this is not possible for me:

```
$ sudo mv profile_default profile_default_bak
mv: cannot move 'profile_default' to 'profile_default_bak': Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?
So far tried:

- checked permissions & ownership, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430655/407261:

  `$ ls -l
  drwxr-xr-x 1 drnuke drnuke 512 May 11 13:21 profile_default
  sudo chown -R drnuke profile_default/
  sudo chmod -R 755 profile_default/`
- checked no other terminal/ bash has any open file/folder within that folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:
Close any VSCode window. Instead use the plain bash terminal.

Comment: this is like the worst solution imho, but VScode seems to be the problem here. This works.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts this afternoon. I was using a plain bash terminal, but just having that folder open in VSCode was enough to cause the problem.